# Google's self-driving car and LIDAR interference

Tags: discrete-signals

Firstly: I hope this isn't the wrong place to ask. I'm usually over in the coding forums. But this seemed like the appropriate forum for the question.

It occurred to me that if several of Google's self-driving cars were lined up together at each side of an intersection, there would be tons of untimed backscatter across anything between them, that would make it all but impossible to determine the exact location of an obstacle.

Is there a way for them to put a unique signature on each radar signal so it isn't muddied up by others?

Also, what would be the effect of someone painting one of these cars with a radar gun?

And lastly - and I know this is definitely outside the scope of this forum - is there any biological consequence to crossing an intersection where you're being painted by several dozen LIDAR beams?

Comment: Sunlight is probably a thousand times more dangerous than several dozen LIDAR beams.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?